# Low multicore CPU utilization of SpringBoot and Jakarta MicroProfiles

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I did simple performance comparison of SpringBoot versus Jakarta MicroProfile servers. Projects is available at:

https://github.com/HotswapProjects/pingperf

https://github.com/HotswapProjects/pingperf-spring-boot

The test uses Docker for simple server embedding, and JMeter as a client. The SpringBoot and Microprofiles based on Tomcat9 are using default Tomcat's thread pool settings  (maxThreads=200). There is one problem I can't resolve. If the server is under heavy load from JMeter (50 threads, hardware Ryzen 1600, os linux), then CPU utilization is only 60% (checked in htop). I did the tests also out of Docker and there is no improvement, CPU utilization is still 60%. Is it possible to tune Tomcat9 settings to reach 100% CPU utilization in this test or is it platform problem?

Comment: Why do you think that a higher CPU utilization would improve the performance?

Comment: CPU utilization should be in this case nearly 100% isn't it? There are enough of threads in thread pool and enough of JMeter's clients to use CPU up to 100%.It look like there is some blocking operation.

Comment: But is the perfromance bad?

Comment: At least for performance test it is bad, since it use 60% percent of CPU instead of 100%

Comment: You say that you have maxThreads of 200. Did you monitor the thread pool? Did you have some waits?

Comment: I'm using "htop" in linux where CPU utilization per thread is obvious. Actual thread pool size is little bit more then 50threads and utilization per thread is ~7%. I've used visual VM as well, but htop seems to me better since it shows structured time consumption user/system time.

Comment: When you were using VisualVM did you see any waiting threads?

Comment: Btw. I just had a look at your code and see synchronized methods. I assume that you are killing the performance by yourself

Comment: ClientPooler-1/2 are running, pool threads are alternating Park/Running state.

Comment: Additionally JMeter is using 300% CPU power, SpringBoot server 500% (in case of Ryzen1600 the full power is 1200%)

Comment: I've remove the critical section from code, but it was too short to have any impact on performance, which does not changed. Still 60% CPU time.

Comment: Why do you think that the CPU is the bottleneck? It's clearly elsewhere else.

Comment: A don't do any conclusions about bottleneck, only speculating that it could be in I/O between JMeter and PingPerf, may be it can be related to my Ryzen 1600 architecture. There are no visible locks in jstack samples. The problem can be also related to Tomcat in some way, since both Meecrowave and SpringBoot (both based on Tomcat) perform well in single thread and bad under heavy load. Both have overall test CPU utilization ~60% under heavy load, on the other hand the OpenLiberty is better under heavy load, with CPU utilization ~90% - that is very interesting point.